# Using contentEditable inside Flutter's webview

Tags: flutter

For an application I need a document that is able to record and display among each other any type (text, audio, video, HTML, maybe PDF) that the user enters or inserts.
At first I wanted to use a listview with different types of widgets (textfields, video via plugin, webview via plugin etc.), but it seemed much too complicated to me. For example, how could I have selected parts of a text field, the following image and parts of the next text field at the same time?

Actually, the document format that I need already exists: HTML. If you set the attribute "contentEditable" accordingly, it is not a big problem to let the user change the document in any way with the help of JS. And this is exactly my problem: If I use the Webview (Developer Preview) of the Flutter team (webview_flutter), the attribute "contentEditable" is apparently ignored.  I can't mark text and no keyboard appears.
Am I doing something wrong or does the plugin not (yet) support this attribute? Otherwise, is there an alternative? I have to say that I am an absolute beginner in Flutter.